# Can I move any partition freely when using UEFI?

Tags: partition, grub, uefi, boot-loader, bios

In BIOS,

- booting is two or three stages, both of which will end up calling the final-stage bootloader code in the boot block of a partition.
- Is that the reason why I need to reinstall GRUB2 when moving `/` partition which contains `/boot` (according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/299886/partitions-is-it-safe-to-move-partition-containing-boot and https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)?

In UEFI,

- some said  booting is one stage, because all bootloader code is in a dedicated EFI boot partition. Is that true?
- Does that mean I can move any partition  (even if Lubuntu is installed on it), and still can boot, without having to do anything with bootloader?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Define stage. 2. You have to ensure your firmware can still find your UEFI partition, ie, partition with partition type C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B

Comment: (1) Two stag booting: MBR of boot disk -> boot sector of a partition. Three state booting: MBR of boot disk -> some sector following MBR of boot disk -> boot sector of a partition.  One stage booting: EFI boot partition? (2) I move my `/` partition. Do you imply moving `/` partition also moves EFI boot partition?

Comment: (1) Definition is not an example. UEFI firmware runs `grubx64.efi`, which needs to load other grub modules. You've been told about concepts, I'm not gonna say it again.(2)No. UEFI firmware find your ESP by its partition type in GPT.  I assume you've known GPT structure.

Comment: You might enjoy http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html; basically "yes, there are no block-related ties but rather filesystem-related ones, as long as you use e.g. UUIDs you should be able to move partitions, maybe excluding ESP".